# What is the difference between useEffect and useMemo?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I would like to understand the use-case of both.

Comment: There are many articles written about this. https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/react-usememo-and-when-you-should-use-it-e69a106bbb02 this is one

Comment: I'd definitely suggest reading through the documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo

Answer (score 4):

`useEffect` allows you to *do something* (asynchronously) when a value changes (or when the component first renders). The "do something" may be anything - maybe you want to make an API call, or set state. or something else.

`useMemo` is quite different - using it allows you to *compute a value* only when necessary, and use it (synchronously). As the React docs show as an example:

```
const memoizedValue = useMemo(() => computeExpensiveValue(a, b), [a, b]);
```

The `computeExpensiveValue` is *only* there to compute an expensive value, which should be pure - it shouldn't contain anything else like setting state.

> For example, when a component loads and I want to make a backend call. Do I use, useEffect or useMemo?

In such a situation, you're not computing a value synchronously, you're *taking an action* which sounds like it results in setting state asynchronously, so `useEffect` is definitely the more appropriate choice.

Comment: This was extremely helpful and all the links from everyone else. Thank you.